# Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION flag usage

Tags: android, file, permissions, android-intent

I'm facing with the following problem:
I created application where user can keep his own private files and I need to pass these files to default viewers (PDFViewer for example).

The problem is that files are private and PDFViewer has no access to my files. I solved this issue using approach that is used in email clients - I created content provider where I return ParcelFileDescriptor.

Now it works great, but I faced with new problem - documentation says I need to use `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag when I pass URI to PDFViewer, but in my case it works well even without this flag and even with "android:grantUriPermissions="false""

Looks like now my files become not private because of content provider.

How to make it honor `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - I forgot to add "android:readPermission" flag to my provider